# Android - onActivityResult from DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a webview app and I want to upload image files from camera of from gallery to my web page.

I successfully implemented the camera upload but now I'm trying to implement a DialogFragment to let user choose from where upload the file.

The code is in a fragment and I can't pass camera results to onActivityResult function, this is the DialogFragment class`public static class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {

```
    private Button buttonCamera;

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.mysite.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                finalphotoURI = photoURI;
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    public EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Get field from view
        buttonCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera);
        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }

        });
    }
}`
```

And this is my onActivityResult class:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_FILE_PICKER)
    {
        if(mFilePathCallback5!=null)
        {
            if (finalphotoURI != null) {
                mFilePathCallback5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{ finalphotoURI });
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback5 = null;
    }
}
```

**How can I pass finalphotoURI to onActivityResult function?**

Answer (score 0):

change your dialogFragment into an appCompatActivity and change it's theme from manifest to dialog and Call StartActivityForResult() and then get the result with that function

Comment: Sorry for the question (I'm a newbie) but how can I convert dialogFragment into appCompatActivity?

Comment: change this public static class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {  into public static class EditNameDialog extends AppCompatActivity{

Comment: and move your codes in oncrrateview and onview created to this      @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}

Comment: First of all thank you for your support! 
I made the changes but I cannot change the theme of this app because it is essential for this app that is built with fragments. Is there any other way, using DialogFragments, to obtain the same result?

Thanks again!

Comment: yes you can save data with shared prefrences in fragment and then get data from shared prefrences in your activity